# Code behind file is not generating and Test are not showing up in visual studio 2019

Tags: c#, specflow

I am new to spec flow. I created console project then I have installed specflow, Specflow Nunit, and Spec flow ms build 2.3.2 versions, specflow for visual studio 2019 and Nunit3 Test adapter. After created the feature file but feature file not generating code behind file and also NO Tests are showing in Test Explorer. I know already there are lot of questions related to this. I tried different ways but no luck. If some one help me on this really appreciate.

Thanks in Advance.

Package.config file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
<package id="Microsoft.CodeCoverage" version="16.1.1" targetFramework="net472" />
<package id="Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk" version="16.1.1" targetFramework="net472" />
<package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="9.0.1" targetFramework="net472" />
<package id="NUnit" version="3.0.0" targetFramework="net472" />
<package id="SpecFlow" version="2.3.2" targetFramework="net472" />
<package id="SpecFlow.NUnit" version="2.3.2" targetFramework="net472" />
```

App.config file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
<configSections>
<section name="specFlow" type="TechTalk.SpecFlow.Configuration.ConfigurationSectionHandler, 
TechTalk.SpecFlow" />
</configSections>
<startup> 
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2" />
</startup>
```

[image: <code>enter image description here</code>]

Comment: That's a fairly old version version of specflow. Try using v 3.1.62 or later. You also need to install SpecFlow.Tools.MsBuild.Generation. If you do want to use an older version I would have look at the documentation as you'll need to specify the unitTestProvider in app.config. See [here](https://specflow.org/documentation/configuration/) - look for the 'Configuring Your Unit Test Provider' heading.

Comment: Okay,I will try and let you if it works.thanks for your help.